# JavaFX2, LineChart symbols and CSS

Tags: java, css, charts, javafx

I am trying to customise a line chart with CSS. I would like to:

- Show legend item symbol (i.e. a legend with all series and their line color)
- Not showing line serie symbol (i.e. do not show data points in chart)

I have try the following:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #20ABD9; }
.default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #F19A2A; }

.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: transparent; }
.default-color1.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: transparent; }
```

Result is there is no more line chart symbol, as expected, but no more symbols in chart legends.

Then, if I set a non-transparent color in background-color, there is still symbols in chart.

I am not sure it is possible.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide chart symbol.

```
lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
```

[Oracle LineChart article](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm#CIHGBCFI)

Comment: But what if you want to mix line and scatter graphs on the same LineChart?